# model design for object that can belong to multiple other objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to build a simple application with 3 types of objects:

- Article (1st Day in RoR, Why PHP is still awesome, RoR vs. PHP)
- Author (Bob, Steve, Jen)
- Tags (RoR, PHP)

An author writes an article, and and make appropriate tags.

so:

```
author has many articles; article belongs to author
```

But what about tags? I want both articles and authors to have tags.

I can imagine that:

```
author has many tags; article has many tags
```

But what about the declaration on the tags model?

```
tag belongs to authors; tag belongs to articles
```

Will the two belongs_to interfere with each other?

What i fear is that tag will require both an author and article parent. and in the event where it has both types of parents, deleting one would delete the tag and the other parent due to foreign key constraints in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [polymorphyc associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :as => :taggable
end
```

Comment: this is extremely helpful. i have people tell me that i should just declare belongs_to :author; belongs_to :article simultaneously in tag. what is the difference in this approach and potential advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: the main difference is if you declare 2 belongs_to lines, then you need to have 2 foreign keys in the table, and if you'll have more taggable things - you will need to add foreign keys to your table. And polymorphyc association will use 1 key and 1 column for handling type. And you can use it just the same way you are using common assciation: tag.authors, tag.articles, article.tag, etc.

Comment: so my understanding is that polymorphic association will only allow each tag to have one belonging. so that would prevent a tag to belong to multiple authors and articles at the same time. seems like the belongs_to :author; belongs_to :article approach will work better.

Comment: hmmmm actually the belongs_to doesn't fit you much, as tag should have many articles (1 tag can be assigned to different articles/authors), and the article/author can have many tags, right? if yes, maybe the better way would be to use [has_and_belongs_to_many association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association)

Comment: @alony : can you pls come online in gmail. Its very urgent.. Please Sister :(

Comment: What if each tag instance must have both an article and an author ?

Comment: @MoussaSarr technically then you need different names for the association (tagger and tagged, for instance) and the Tag model would have 2 lines.
but that should really make sense in the business model as well